# TypeScript assumes merged interfaces are of type never

Tags: typescript

I have created a type by merging some interfaces. For some reason TypeScript assumes my type is going to be of type `never`. Could you point out what I am doing wrong so that TypeScript does that?

```
type OrganizationAccount = Account & DetailedAccount & AccountSelection;

interface Account {
  name: string;
  created_on: string;
}

interface DetailedAccount {
  account_type: string;
  status: string;
}

interface AccountSelection {
  isSelected?: boolean;
}
```

My first API request returns just the `Account` properties (`name` and `created_on`).
The user may get the details by clicking a button which then makes another request and after it receives extra properties spreads the account object adding `DetailedAccount` properties.

```
function getAccountDetails(account: OrganizationAccount) {
  setOrganizationAccounts((prevState: OrganizationAccount[]) => {
    return prevState.map(organizationAccount => {
      return organizationAccount.name === account.name
        ? {
          ...organizationAccount,
          ...accountDetailsRes,
          }
        : organizationAccount;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Later I am checking whether `account_type` is present and based on that I display different results however, this is where TypeScript thinks my `account` variable is of type `never`.

```
function accountType(account: OrganizationAccount) {
  if (!('account_type' in account)) { // Here account === OrganizationAccount
    console.log('account', account);  // Here account === never

    return 'Loading...';
  }

  return account.account_type;
}
```

Comment: `if (!('account_type' in account)) {` is always false in the TypeScript world because the property `account_type` is mandatory in `OrganizationAccount`.

Comment: @jabaa is my `OrganizationAccount` incorrectly merged then or how do I check that there's not `account_type` just yet? I could use `account.hasOwnProperty('account_type')` but it didn't feel right as it doesn't take TypeScript type into account.

Comment: `OrganizationAccount` is `{
  name: string;
  created_on: string;
  account_type: string;
  status: string;
  isSelected?: boolean;
}`. You can't omit `account_type`. According to the type the property `account_type` always has to be set.

Answer (score 1):

`if (!('account_type' in account)) {` is always false in the TypeScript world because the property `account_type` is mandatory in `OrganizationAccount`.

You probably want to set `OrganizationAccount` to

```
type OrganizationAccount = (Account | Account & DetailedAccount) & AccountSelection;
```

I prefer

```
type OrganizationAccount = (Account | DetailedAccount) & AccountSelection;

interface Account {
  name: string;
  created_on: string;
}

interface DetailedAccount extends Account {
  account_type: string;
  status: string;
}

interface AccountSelection {
  isSelected?: boolean;
}
```

A working example:

```
type OrganizationAccount = (Account | Account & DetailedAccount) & AccountSelection;

interface Account {
  name: string;
  created_on: string;
}

interface DetailedAccount {
  account_type: string;
  status: string;
}

interface AccountSelection {
  isSelected?: boolean;
}

let a: OrganizationAccount = {
  name: 'a',
  created_on: 'string',
  isSelected: false
};
a.name = 'a';
a.created_on = 'string';
a.isSelected = true;

let b: OrganizationAccount = {
  name: 'b',
  created_on: 'string',
  isSelected: false,
  account_type: 'type',
  status: 'string'
};
b.name = 'b';
b.created_on = 'string';
b.isSelected = true;
b.account_type = 'type';
b.status = 'string';

function f(account: OrganizationAccount) {
  console.log(account.name);
  if ('account_type' in account) {
    console.log(account.account_type);
  }
}

f(a);
f(b);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=47&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgcwIYDsCWAvJw0HsUCCAxkbgK4rBQC8UAFMaRVQD5SPmVQBkUAIhGBI0AGwgATDswCUPdiU7AAyhDFEc+ANwAobWkoQ4AMyRFoUrgG9tUKCiQBbCAC4oAZ2Bx9CHbaJwIbAkAfXxXDy8UH20AX119YEMTM35BYTFJBWYoa1tTJkpg0Ehwz29fdyFgMjdSyOi4vQNjU3MsyhU1DRQcmyg0N06IdQkAflcAI1xcMVQdRrEqJFd4ZHQsbosqWly7RxcoAHIkQ4AaPv9AxPFQlFdDiO8zvoGhkfFXExE3CFidJAAdPYnDQjid-gDLkEbvhQQ8ylFDhDXqphtdQZ4yBAdNpFlAJitEKhMNg8IR2tterZgQdDhNnn4AtDbvdHojzrYUV0JJ8kN8IByoPlFEVwLTihAGZVsDVWQiEIc-toJkD9nD6ToVVDrrc4WyFZqAVy0RIMXAsYbhcxRZA4RKkcqAR4ZW49fKHdojBR1GSoEY6FbKIS1iTNhTZLtSCg3DMIACRLgEAGKaqnNIKmgjPRjhSbZL+j1A8AI30-PgY2J44nkwVgACi3n0304o1-Ugm-6JumgA)

Comment: Yes but then I have issues in other places like `Property 'isSelected' does not exist on type 'OrganizationAccount'.
  Property 'isSelected' does not exist on type 'Account'.`

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I changed my codes. Probably I had a problem with the operator precedence.

Comment: No idea why I am seeing this: `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'OrganizationAccount'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'DetailedAccount'.`

Whenever I type this `type OrganizationAccount = Account | DetailedAccount & AccountSelection;` my prettier/lint converts it to `type OrganizationAccount =
  | Account
  | (DetailedAccount & AccountSelection);`

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Maybe you have an outdated toolset. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgcwIYDsCWAvJw0HsUCCAxkbgK4rBQC8UAFMaRVQD5SPmVQBkUAIhGBI0AGwgATDswCUPdiU7AAyhDFEc+ANwAobWkoQ4AMyRFoUrgG9tUKCiQBbCAC4oAZ2Bx9CHbaJwIbAkAfXxXDy8UH20AX119YEMTM35BYTFJBWYoa1tTJkpg0Ehwz29fdyFgMjdSyOi4vQNjU3MsyhU1DRQcmyg0N06IdQkAflcAI1xcMVQdRrEqJFd4ZHQsbosqWly7RxcoAHII70OAGj7-QMTxUJRXY7Ko876BoZHxVxMRNwhYnSQADp7E4aEcTs8AYCrkFbvgwY96ocoW9VMMbmDPGQIDptIsoBMVohUJhsHhCO1tr1bCCDojThc-AFYXcHhCEC9bKiuhIvkgfhBGVB8ooiuA6ezOZVsDU2U8Of9tBNgfsEZKdMqYTc7mr5cilYDueiJJi4NiNYCRcwxZBdUiLR4ZW47adcUCrYVitBaPTIUA

Comment: I have changed the type to what you suggested but in some places it complains about this: `disabled={!data.account_type}`. 
`Property 'account_type' does not exist on type 'OrganizationAccount'.
  Property 'account_type' does not exist on type 'Account & AccountSelection'.` It gives me a headache...

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I can't fix code you didn't post. In your question you have the problem that you merge types and all properties are mandatory. But obviously you don't want that. So I changed the type to solve the problem in your question. Of course, it's possible that such a change can break some other code. But your current error message looks like a misunderstanding of the concept. Either a property is mandatory or not. In your example code you can't initialize an object without a property and later add it.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk An object is either an `Account` or an `DetailedAccount`. You are not allowed to set `account_type` and `status` for a basic account. You can't initialize a `DetailedAccount` without `account_type` and `status`. An object either doesn't have both properties or does have both properties but an object can't have only one of these properties at any time.

Comment: Check out [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgcwIYDsCWAvJw0HsUCCAxkbgK4rBQC8UAFMaRVQD5SPmVQBkUAIhGBI0AGwgATDswCUPdiU7AAyhDFEc+ANwAobWkoQ4AMyRFoUrgG9tUKCiQBbCAC4oAZ2Bx9CHbaJwIbAkAfXxXDy8UH20AX119YEMTM35BYTFJBWYoa1tTJkpg0Ehwz29fdyFgMjdSyOi4vQNjU3MsyhU1DRQcmyg0N06IdQkAflcAI1xcMVQdRtIUDygHED5sJFd4ZHQsbosqWly7RxcoAHII73OAGj7-QMTxUJRXS7Ko29idbSMKdTwPQGfAGSAmGTo4g2W0QqEw2EBB1kxwC1TgPQAhFChAA6fKKIrgCDzbRAA)

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk You can't unconditionally access `account_type`. You don't know if the object contains this property. `OrganizationAccount` can either be `{
  name: string;
  created_on: string;
  isSelected?: boolean;
}` or `{
  name: string;
  created_on: string;
  account_type: string;
  status: string;
  isSelected?: boolean;
}`. There is no `account_type` in the former case.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk You can replace `return !data.account_type;` with `return !('account_type' in data);`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but TypeScript doesn't work at runtime so if account_type is not initially in data but then after the details request it does, how is that handled?

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk It's handled exactly as you see it in your error messages. As long as it's unclear if the object contains a property you can't unconditionally access that property.